# Simplify list comprehension

Tags: python, list, csv, list-comprehension

```
import csv
with open('chicago.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
   reader = [{key: value for key, value in row.items()}     
        for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

Can someone simplify the code and explain its arguments from line three i.e `reader = ...` .

Answer (score 4):

The comprehension is just overkill, since

```
{key: value for key, value in row.items()}
```

is a complex way of doing

```
row.copy()
```

You don't even need to copy each dict row, so a good simplification to generate the list of dict rows would be just:

```
import csv
with open('chicago.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
   reader = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True))
```

one line, but no list/dict comprehension anymore, as it isn't needed.